# How to set user in multi allow people picker control using javascript

Tags: 2013, javascript, people-picker

I want set the value to the people picker control which is multi allowed.

I have a code which assigns only single value to it, which is as below:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert('Hello');
        SetAndResolvePeoplePicker("Members","domain\\user");
    });

    function SetAndResolvePeoplePicker(fieldName, userAccountName) {

        var controlName = fieldName;

        var peoplePickerDiv = $("[id$='ClientPeoplePicker'][title='" + controlName + "']");

        var peoplePickerEditor = peoplePickerDiv.find("[title='" + controlName + "']");

        var spPeoplePicker = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[peoplePickerDiv[0].id];

        peoplePickerEditor.val(userAccountName);


        spPeoplePicker.AddUnresolvedUserFromEditor(true);
    }
```

All things I have applied in is `jslink`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer:

Just simply call the function multiple times.

Such as:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert('Hello');
    SetAndResolvePeoplePicker("Members","domain\\user0");
    SetAndResolvePeoplePicker("Members","domain\\user1");
    SetAndResolvePeoplePicker("Members","domain\\user3");
});
```

It will add all the users to people picker.
Hope this helps to other also...!!! :-)

Comment: Please make sure to remember to mark your answer as correct it helps keep the Q&A tidy and people to find the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding values directly to people picker object, not through html input.

Replace this

```
peoplePickerEditor.val(userAccountName);
spPeoplePicker.AddUnresolvedUserFromEditor(true);
```

With this

```
spPeoplePicker.AddUserKeys(userAccountName);
```

`AddUserKeys` accepts ";" separated list of domain names, adds them to people picker and tries to resolve it.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but the solution you suggested is not working, it throws error `Object doesn't support property or method 'AddUserKeys'` on the statement `spPeoplePicker.AddUserKeys(userAccountName);`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, **spservices** has a solution.

[Here is the documentation](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=$().SPServices.SPFindPeoplePicker).